# How to compare two OneNote sections (*.one files)

Tags: comparison, microsoft-onenote

I am syncing my OneNote notebooks using [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com/) (something like Dropbox) and sometimes, it generates "conflicts", i.e. suddenly there are two sections like this:

```
MyNotes.one
MyNotes (conflict at ...).one
```

Such notebook typically contains tens of pages and I don't want to go through them and compare them manually. Can you recommend a tool / procedure that would help to easily find any potential differences? I usually use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare just about anything but it doesn't support *.one file format.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to compare only 2 OneNote *sections* from 2 .one files:

1. Open both .one files with OneNote (version >= 2010)
2. Export both sections to the *single web page*, `.mht` format
3. Use your favorite text comparison tool to compare the exported `.mht` files

If you need to compare multiple sections (i.e. the whole notebook), the process is slightly more cumbersome: use the same method, but choose to export the notebooks as `.xps` files.

Then unzip the `.xps` files, and use a directory comparison tool (the text of your notes is stored in plain text).

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of anything that will do this, but you might find this article useful in understand why this happens. It explains how OneNote has its own built-in sync'ing and recommends against trying to sync a .one file with other off-the-shelf sync tools.
http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?i=onenote-sync

I get these frequently because I use Dropbox to sync between OneNote on my desktop and Outline+ on my iPad. Hopefully Outline+ will get the SkyDrive sync worked out soon to alleviate all of this.

Comment: On Super User, we prefer that answers consist of more than a link. Could you summarize the content from behind that link?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing OneNote Notebooks/Sections/Page:

**Export your version1 / version2 by following steps:**

1. Click on `File` > `Export`, you'll see this screen:
   [image]
2. Choose what to export (on the left pane)
3. Choose PDF format

Now take the 2 PDF versions and drop then in some PDF online comparator (e.g. a very nice one: https://draftable.com/compare )